# What is the cockpit shown in this picture?

Tags: aircraft-identification, cockpit

What is the cockpit shown in the picture below?

[image: Cockpit]

Comment: Is the bottom picture relevant? If not, can it be cut-out?

Comment: There are two...

Comment: Judging by the way the shadows appear on the 'windows' I'd say this isn't a real cockpit at all, but a simulator.

Answer (score 15):

The cockpit shown in the photo is of a **Boeing 747-400**.

You can tell that it must be a 747 by the fact that it has 4 thrust levers (so 4 engines) in the typical Boeing design. The 6 screens with the EFIS controllers rule out anything older than the 747-400 (like a B707 or older B747 variants). The large gear lever with the 3 positions rules out the new 747-8 variant.

Here is a cockpit picture for comparison:

[image: Boeing 747-400 Cockpit]
<sup>(image source: [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:JAL_Boeing_747-446_flight_deck.jpg))</sup>

Comment: In addition, it has yokes instead of side sticks, making it a Boeing instead of an Airbus.

Comment: The top picture looks like it *may* be in a simulator, rather than an actual aircraft. Based on the screen around the windows.  Though if an actual jet had fabric around the outside of the flightdeck windows... can't say for certain.

Comment: @SnakeDoc The Airbus A300 and A310 have yokes as well. But no Airbus quad-jet has yokes, they all have sidesticks.

Comment: @Bianfable Exactly. So the presence of yokes narrows down the make to a Boeing, furthering the conclusion.